# how to make an array one spot longer with the new thing at the end? Array cant change length

Tags: java

I have been working on this for hours. I really need some help.

Here is a class called Thing and the specs about it:
//I dont know if this class is related to the problem below. I just put it here.

*Thing* encompasses both *persons* and *threats*. This abstract class implements both Representable and Passable (though it relegates all methods from Passable to child classes). //you can ignore some classes mentioned in the specs

**Fields**

```
private Coord loc, prevLoc
public final String repr
protected java.io.PrintStream log
protected Map map
```

**Methods**

```
public Thing(Coord c, String repr, Map map, PrintStream log). Initializes the fields. Both loc and prevLoc are set to the given coordinate c. (This is the only time they'll match).
public abstract void doAction(). All things can do an action. People might move, and threats might spawn or kill. This will be overridden lower in the class hierarchy.
public Coord getLoc(). Returns the loc.
public Coord getPrevLoc(). Returns the prevLoc.
public void setLoc(Coord c). Updates both prevLoc and loc appropriately.
@Override public String repr(). Returns the field.
@Override public String toString(). Returns the concatenation of repr() and getLoc(). For instance, an Avoider at location (2,3) would return "a@(2,3)".
```

I created this class as following:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
public abstract class Thing implements Representable,Passable {
  private Coord loc, prevLoc;
  public final String repr;
  protected java.io.PrintStream log;
  protected Map map;

  public Thing(Coord c, String repr, Map map, PrintStream log){
    this.loc = c;
    this.prevLoc = c;
    this.repr = repr;
    this.map = map;
    this.log = log;
  }

  public abstract void doAction();

  public Coord getLoc(){
    return loc;
  }

  public Coord getPrevLoc(){
    return prevLoc;
  }

  public void setLoc(Coord c){
   prevLoc=loc;
   loc=c;
  }

  @Override 
  public String repr(){
    return repr;
  }

  @Override 
  public String toString(){
    return repr+"@("+loc+")";
  }

}
```

There is another class called Map in which the problem happened.

A Map represents all the spots and things in a simulation, and provides some support methods for them as well. You will likely need to create the enumerations, interfaces, and many of the Thing classes before you can pull them all together with the Map class.

**Fields**

```
Spot[][] floorplan
Thing[] things
java.io.PrintStream log
```

**Methods**// I just skipped some methods not related to my question.

```
Map(String filename, PrintStream log). Reads the given file to construct a map and all spots/things on it.
```

Any messages (such as safety or death messages) from this map will be sent to log. Any "map file" that is named in the first argument ("String filename") is assumed to have the same number of characters in each line, each line ends with a "\n" character, and each character is assumed to be one of our valid characters (see 1.2). If any of these assumptions is invalidated, or the file doesn't even exist, your program does not need to function (behavior is undefined). You may add throws IOException to your method signature as necessary.

```
public void addThing(Thing a). 

Occasionally new things should be added (usually these are threats that 
have spawned more spots of slime or haze). 
Accept a new Thing (assumed to be on the map), and cause 
the things field to be one spot longer, with this new one at the end. 
Remember, arrays can't change length. How will you get around this?
```

My Map class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Map{
  Spot[][] floorplan;
  Thing[] things; //= new Thing[0];//initialize things
  java.io.PrintStream log;
  int rows=0;//
  int cols=0;//
  Map(String filename, PrintStream log) throws IOException{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File(filename));
    ......
    ......
  } 

 int i =0;
 public void addThing(Thing a){
    i++;  
    things = Arrays.copyOf(things, i);
    things[i-1]=a;   
  }
```

**Im stuck at addThing method. Did I create it right as the specs requires? I spent hours debugging addThing method and tried a lot of ways to write different codes. But this method can not pass tests. Why????**

Here is the test case:

```
@Test (timeout=2000) public void map_addThing3(){
    Map m = stringToMap(".....\n.....\n.....\n");
    Zoolander z1 = new Zoolander(new Coord(1,2),m, m.log);
    Zoolander z2 = new Zoolander(new Coord(1,2),m, m.log);
    Follower  f1 = new Follower (new Coord(1,2),m, m.log);

    m.addThing(z1);
    assertThingsMatch(m.things, new Thing[]{z1});
    m.addThing(z2);
    assertThingsMatch(m.things, new Thing[]{z1,z2});
    m.addThing(f1);
    assertThingsMatch(m.things, new Thing[]{z1,z2,f1});
  }
```

Comment: `ArrayList`...you might also like to take a look at [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) which can copy part of whole of an existing array into another, which you can use to enlarge or shrink arrays...which is basically what `ArrayList` does...

Comment: I tried arraylist, but it actually does not work for the test case..

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct, but you can do it without the `i` member :

```
 public void addThing(Thing a)
 {
    things = Arrays.copyOf(things, things.length+1);
    things[things.length-1]=a;   
 }
```

Comment: Do I need to give []things an initial length like 0？

Comment: @ecocs You have to initialize `things` to a non-null reference. If you want it to start as an empty array, `things = new Thing [0]`; will do.

Comment: @ecocs If you get NullPointerException, this means `things` was not initialized, so it contains null.

Comment: I do initialize it. Thing[] things = new Thing[0]. but it cannot pass tests. I dont know why...

Answer (score 0):

You make a new array, one spot longer.  You copy every item from the old array into the new one, and then you set the last "new" spot with the desired value.

Or, you could use an `ArrayList`, which does this for you, in an optimized manner.

Comment: Could you please write this arraylist for me? I created an arraylist, but it didnot solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The arraylist is a Java library class, known as `java.util.ArrayList` and is created with the "new" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Define a new array with more space, copy old content into it and then append new objects or values.

It may be a bad idea when the array is already big. And if you frequently do this "add one" job, it consumes a lot of unnecessary time.

Try to come with other alternative data structure like arrayList and LinkedList.